# Custom numeric input

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, user-interface, input

Cheers! I'm not good in front-end, so, designer-peeps, do you have any idea how to realize input similar to this, from what should I start?

[image: input]

Comment: look for some jquery plugin there are many jquery plugins more attractive then this design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is ***the very basic example*** of how it can be done. Of course you need to change the styles and adjust the elements upon your needs. However the idea should be understandable.

*HTML:*

```
<div class="spin"><span>&ndash;</span><input value="0" /><span>+</span></div>
```

*CSS:*

```
.spin {
    display: inline-block;
}
.spin span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 2px;
    background: #ff0;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.spin span:first-child {
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
.spin input {
    width: 40px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

*JavaScript:*

```
var spins = document.getElementsByClassName("spin");
for (var i = 0, len = spins.length; i < len; i++) {
    var spin = spins[i],
        span = spin.getElementsByTagName("span"),
        input = spin.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

    input.onchange = function() { input.value = +input.value || 0; };
    span[0].onclick = function() { input.value = Math.max(0, input.value - 1); };
    span[1].onclick = function() { input.value -= -1; };
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/fPQvK/

Comment: First of all - thank you for reply! Second - what if I need not single input, but some number of inputs like this?

Answer (score 1):

Try html5 [input type number](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_number):

```
<input type="number"/>
```

Lacks firefox support :(

EDIT: or create your one as Jakub suggested:

```
 <input type="text" id="numberInput" value="1"/>
 <input type="button" id="btnIncrement" value="increment" onclick="increment();" />
 <input type="button" id="btnDecrement" value="decrement" onclick="decrement();" />

function increment(){
    var input = document.getElementById('numberInput');
    input.value = parseInt(input.value) + 1;
}

function decrement(){
    var input = document.getElementById('numberInput');
    input.value = parseInt(input.value) - 1;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZwNkb/1/)

Comment: Thank you for answering, but it very very very basic, me more interested in to how to manage those +/- buttons, how to customize them?

Comment: @Nikita see this jquery plugin: http://1stwebmagazine.com/stepper-jquery-number-input-plugin

Comment: This input would be very hard, or even _impossible_, to style. I recommend using a classic `type="text"`, adding two `<buttons>` and binding `onClick` events to (de/in)crementation in **JS**.