# HTML5 number field arrows customization

Tags: html, forms

Can I customize

```
<input type='number'>
```

field to show all the time it's arrows? By default it's hidden till the field is has no focus. Below is what I'm talking about.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox and IE don't have such behavior.  So, I assume you are working with Google Chrome.

```
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

FYI. UA stylesheet has the following:

```
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    ...
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

input:enabled:read-write:-webkit-any(:focus,:hover)::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

[html.css](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink/trunk/Source/core/css/html.css#l489)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I am pretty sure `type="number"` is supported in the latest versions of IE and Firefox

Comment: Firefox always show a spin button, and IE never shows a spin button.

Answer (score 1):

The UI and behavior of `<input type='number'>`, as well as all the other HTML5 input types (e.g., `type='date'`, etc), is browser and/or system dependent. To make the arrows always visible, you'd need to use a custom JS solution.

Comment: by saying 'JS solution' you mean to build this number field from scratch - is that right ?

Comment: @OskarSzura Correct. You'd need markup for the textbox and for the arrows.

Answer (score 0):

Only way that I can think of is... Having two buttons for incrementing and decrementing your `input` and using JS. You won't be using `type="number"` here since the JS will be incrementing and decrementing the number for you.

Here is an example, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15615783/3739658):

**CSS:**

```
.spin {
    display: inline-block;
}
.spin span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.spin span:first-child {
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
.spin input {
    width: 40px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var spins = document.getElementsByClassName("spin");
for (var i = 0, len = spins.length; i < len; i++) {
    var spin = spins[i],
        span = spin.getElementsByTagName("span"),
        input = spin.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

    input.onchange = function() { input.value = +input.value || 0; };
    span[0].onclick = function() { input.value = Math.max(0, input.value - 1); };
    span[1].onclick = function() { input.value -= -1; };
}
```

**Note:** Change `background: #fff;` to change the arrow colors. There are other neat examples available on the web as well!

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6bVD7/1)**

Comment: Would make more sense using JS if you want to customize your input and for browser compatibility